# Multiple users using same CVS repository on server

Tags: centos, cvs

We use CVS to hold many of our configuration files for applications. We have been trying to standardize on a location to hold each of them, and when initially setup, they work great ;)

```
our basic process is this.. as user APP1
mkdir /configs/
cd /configs
cvs get Prod/client/application
```

This creates a nice set of subdirectories with all our config files, and in theory, is as easy to update as going to the /configs directory, and typing "cvs update Prod".

However, we have lots of developers and admins that seem to forget to SU to the user APP1. so for the initial checkout of the files, it might be done under a different user.. or perhaps they navigate there as themselves, and type:

```
cd /configs
cvs get pre-Prod/client/application
or
cvs get Prod/client/application2
```

Now, nobody else besides them can seem to use CVS with that set of directories.. I can change the owernership of the files, but is there a way to not lock the CVS folder stuff to a certain user?

Maybe I should be asking this on Stack Overflow, but this is more for the administration of the repositories (or to help me fix it all)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

1. Create a dedicated user APP1.
2. Restrict write access to user APP1 in the /config directory.
3. Create a script that checks updates /config directory from CVS with the APP1 credentials.
4. Ask all your developers and admins to use the script to update the /config
   directory.